# Could not find the main class Files\Netbeans. Program will exit

Tags: java, netbeans7.0

Previously everything was fine. I haven't run Netbeans 7.0.1 for two weeks. Now when I start Netbeans I got this error.
I am having Netbeans 7.0.1 and Windows 7 64bit. 
I have to use Netbeans 7.0.1 and JDK 6 for running my project.
I delete windows temporary files, Netbeans cache from 
C:\Users\username.netbeans\7.0\var directory.
I have installed JDK 6 and 7. I have other projects that run fine in Netbeans 7.4 and JDK 7.

I was facing the same problem many times, and after some time after this error netbeans started, but now it doesn't.

I read that this problem usually happens if your PC runs out of memory and you force quit it Netbeans.

Could you help me?
Here is an image
[image]

Here is the error I got in my console:

```
The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console an
it for its own console output.
Closing the console will result in termination of the running progra
Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
Use '--console new' to create a separate console window.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files\Net
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\NetBeans
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Could not find the main class: Files\NetBeans.  Program will exit.

Comment: Make sure you do a clean and build before you try and run it.  You might also consider making sure that the "main class" is set within the project properties

Comment: I am facing this problem on Netbeans start, I can't even find view my projects @MadProgrammer

Comment: I tried many times, I restar my machine though, but this does not helped me

Comment: I double-clicked on C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0.1\bin\netbeans.exe. Do you mean on this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88959/discussion-between-vikifor-and-willshackleford).